# Give permission to play music but not to copy the files

Tags: linux, user-permissions

Under linux, I want to create a way through which a user can play some music files, but the files cannot be copied (by the same user).

I know it sounds paradoxical, somehow, but I kinda have an idea which I don't really know how to implement.

Let **user1** own the music files and we want **user2** to be able to play them, but not to copy them. I am thinking of having the files accessible for the music player (**audacious**, for example) but unreadable for the **user2**. **user2** could then launch **audacious**, which can play the music files, but cannot access them himself.

Can this be achieved, probably by using user permissions for groups and others.

Comment: no. there is absoultely NO difference between "playing" a digital music file and "copying" a digital music file. in both cases, the data gets read off the disk. you cannot tell the difference between "load for playing" and "load for copying". The same applies for **ANY** file type.

Comment: [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) might help.

Comment: Take a look at this answer on unix stack exchange http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69203/selinux-can-i-disable-copying-of-certain-files

Comment: You can create a daemon that runs under user1, and receives commands from user2 to play certain track directly to audio. It is possible to capture audio card output, but it will not be exactly the same stream already.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses.

@marc I know there is no difference, but I imagine the following scenario: **user2** cannot read the files but he can launch **audacious**, which in turn CAN read the files. Moreover, **audacious** is the only thing that can read the files and, since it cannot write the files, they cannot be copied.

This seems to be the way they explain it on the link Paul mentioned. Now my problem is how do I tell that only **audacious** can read the files?

Comment: you could make audacious suid to a particular account, then make the audio files be owned by that account. anyone NOT using audacious would have no access.

Comment: Thank you, @MarcB. That worked. Could you please tell me how to mark the answer and close this question?

Comment: comments can't be accepted. that's why they're comments.